# Validation of Refresh Token in authlib

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token, authlib

I want to validate the refresh tokens I obtained earlier from the server. One possibility is to obtain an access token from the server which will implicitly validate the used refresh token. But here the generated access token is of no use to me. Alternatively, I could expose an interface (in "routes.py" of the example Token server) for validating the given refresh tokens through the function:

```
RefreshTokenGrant.authenticate_refresh_token(ref_token)
```

If I understand the flow correctly, I need to get the RefreshTokenGrant object to execute this function which is instantiated here in "authorization_server.py":

```
for grant_cls in self._token_grants:
        if grant_cls.check_token_endpoint(request):
            if request.method in grant_cls.TOKEN_ENDPOINT_HTTP_METHODS:
                return grant_cls(request, self)
```

I could theoretically get this token Grant object from actual authorization object (authlib/specs/rfc6749/authorization_server.py) through the flask authorization server object (flask/oauth2/authorization_server.py) in the Token server example but it seems there is no way to get the former object from the latter. Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

This was easier than I thought. I just used the code from RefreshTokenGrant class in the Token server example and made sure to include the OAuth2Token object:

```
item = OAuth2Token.query.filter_by(refresh_token=request.form.get('refresh_token')).first()
if item and not item.is_refresh_token_expired():
...
```

But probably there is a better way to do this..